# Javascript Event not tied to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I'm having difficulty understanding if there is an event system in JS.  I'm trying to create an event without the DOM in an external .js file.  The goal being in the page:

```
my.namespace.pageNamespace.registerEventListener('loadedData', function(){
//do something here
});
```

and

```
my.namespace.pageNamespace.raiseEvent('loadedData', data);
```

I can probably achieve this in code by:

```
registerEventListener:function(eventName,fn){
//then store to kvp array
}
```

Is there a better way.  Perhaps using jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Take alook at this:  https://gist.github.com/661855